# Help with my tensor tension; how to derive and calculate this rigid body gravity gradient torque?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, physics, mathematics, attitude-determination-and-control

Tensors make me tense.

Imagine a long thin rod in a circular orbit. The gravity gradient will produce a net torque on the rod whenever it is not oriented parallel, or perpendicular to the radius vector (pointing up/down or pointing forward/backward). Let's keep the problem 2D and ignore out-of-plane orientations.

The Coursera video [1: Gravity Gradient Torque Development](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/spacecraft-dynamics-kinetics/1-gravity-gradient-torque-development-sNM1R) from the course by University of Colorado Boulder
Kinetics: Studying Spacecraft Motion taught by Hanspeter Schaub includes the following:

$$ L_G = \frac{3 GM_E}{R_C^5} \mathbf{R_C} \times [I] \mathbf{R_C},$$

which comes from a first order expansion of the local gravity gradient.

He explains that at this point (about `16:30`) that you need to stop and think about coordinate systems and frames, and that's when I start feeling like [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evlrs5Bi_6E) *lower your volume first!*

For an infinitely thin rod in 2D, I am guessing that the [moment of inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors) is just

$$
I =   \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{12}ml^2 & 0\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now what? I need to get a $\sin(2\theta)$ somehow so that the torque will be zero at both 0 and 90 degrees. What sort of tensor magic multiplication can get me there?

[SMAD](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792309710) first edition gives:

$$\frac{3 \mu}{R_0^3} \mathbf{u_e} \times (\mathbf{I} \cdot \mathbf{u_e})$$

where $\mathbf{u_e}$ is the unit vector towards the nadir. It seems to be essentially the same, but with the magical tension-inducing tensor math written slightly differently. Dot product between two vectors gives a scalar, but here I don't know what to do.

In each case $\mathbf{R_C}$ or $\mathbf{R_0}$ are from the center of the Earth to the rod's center of mass.

**Question:** How would I derive that expression for torque in terms of an angle $\theta$ that the rod makes with respect to the nadir, such that the torque has a $\sin(2\theta)$ term, *using my simple 2D moment of inertia?*

Please, no small angle approximations!

---

[image: U. Colorado Boulder Kinetics: Studying Spacecraft Motion Coursera]

[Screen Shot](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/spacecraft-dynamics-kinetics/1-gravity-gradient-torque-development-sNM1R)

[image: SMAD]

[SMAD](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792309710) first edition

Comment: **possibly helpful?** I see a $\sin(2\theta)$ in Eq. A.16 [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-642-25749-0%2F1.pdf) but I've run out of steam...

Comment: @Paul It is from intuition. I know it's got to be there from symmetry.

Comment: Hint: recall that $sin(2\theta)=2sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$.  Everything else should be straight forward from that linked appendix.

Comment: @Paul I'd like to connect the dots. Right now I don't understand how to write the multiplication of the tensor with the vector to its right, obtain a new vector, and then end up with trigonometry. I haven't done this kind of thing in several decades.

Comment: Multiplying a rank 2 tensor to a vector is no different from multiplying a matrix to a vector.  The trigonometric terms come from the euler rotations in the formula for the torque.  Remember:  attitude is everything!

Comment: What book is this appendix from?  There is something that just doesn’t quite look right about their definition of $R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88604/discussion-between-paul-and-uhoh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between the direction of the rod and the direction toward the Earth, measured counter-clockwise. Then in the system of coordinates you used to write $I$ as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{12}ml^2 & 0\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix},
$$
$\mathbf{R_C}$ has the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} R_C\cos\theta \\ R_C\sin\theta\end{array}\right).
$$
Then $I\mathbf{R_C}$ is obtained by matrix multiplication:
$$
I\mathbf{R_C} = \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{12}ml^2R_C\cos\theta \\ 0\end{array}\right),
$$
and the cross product is
$$
\mathbf{R_C}\times I\mathbf{R_C} = - R_C\sin\theta\cdot \frac{1}{12}ml^2R_C\cos\theta = -\frac{1}{24}ml^2R_C^2\sin 2\theta.
$$
(Strictly speaking, the cross product is a three-dimensional vector, but if we restrict ourselves to a plane, then this vector is always perpendicular to this plane, so we can view it as a scalar.)

And the final result is
$$
L_G = -\frac{GM_Eml^2}{8R_C^3}\sin 2\theta.
$$

Comment: That's excellent! I probably shot myself in the foot by trying to force a 3D problem into 2D, rather than just leave some zeros. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can it really be true that the instantaneous angular acceleration for the thin rod is independent of length (to first order), and just $\ddot{\theta} =  \dot{\omega} = -(3GM_E/2R_C^3)\sin(2\theta)$? That maxes out at about 0.4 degrees/minute^2 at 45 degrees; that's pretty cool!

Comment: @uhoh You're welcome. And yes, your formula looks correct.

Comment: sweet! I've [used it here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33781/12102) now.