# Nodal precession effect on attitude?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

When a satellites orbit experiences nodal precession, does this have any effect on the actual attitude or orientation of the satellite?

For example, if the satellite is pointing at a particular star, will it remain pointed at that star?

Comment: Interesting question! There might be some subtle higher order effect depending on the internal mass distribution within the satellite, but I think that a much stronger torque effect would dominate; that due to the radial gravity gradient of Earth alone, never mind the much smaller oblate bit. For more on that see...

Comment: [How does gravity-gradient stabilization work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34276/12102) and [Help with my tensor tension; how to derive and calculate this rigid body gravity gradient torque?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33774/12102) and [Are all or some geostationary satellites tidally locked to the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45329/12102) and [What are damper booms, and how do they facilitate triaxial stabilization?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32434/12102)